# How to manage large amount of data updating in nodejs loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, jobs

I am using node js loopback for managing my API. Actually, i want to update a large amount of data. How can I achieve this using node js. I am searched on google and I saw some articles. In some articles, they say `async` is good to manage the long process. Is there any other tools to manage the large process in the database. I am using MySQL for the database.

Comment: Please define "large": how much data?

Comment: @Richard More than 2 million, its a stock transaction table

Comment: any code to share with us ?

Comment: @user1851595 no, I am just started working on it